# get content from dynamic .txt file using php

Tags: php, html

I am using:

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents("currentstate.txt","r");
echo($file);

?>
```

to display contents of a txt file in a modal window upon request.

The contents of the txt file is dynamic but the php only displays the content as it is when the page was loaded. I need a way to update what the php displays without refreshing the page.

TIA

Comment: You will need to use a combination of php, ajax and html to get this done.

Comment: You'll need to use **Ajax** to accomplish this. Once you load the page sequentially pull the data directly from the txt file.

Answer (score 0):

You will need ajax or Jquery fo this task

Comment: ok, any suggestions on where to start digging into that?
Maybe a snippet or two?